# How to send a WhatsApp message with buttons using Twilio in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, twilio, twilio-php

I am using Twilio with Laravel to build a chatbot.
And I want to attach buttons with each message to like a quick reply.

Comment: SO is for code specific questions. Please show us your progress or where you are stuck. Otherwise you will probably not get answer.

Comment: Can you include some code including the line that is giving you an error? What error are you receiving? What you wish to do is possible

Answer (score 1):

Message templates are the way forward to add [quick reply buttons](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/buttons) to messages. Once the template is approved, you can then respond with the body of the template and the buttons get attached automatically.